# PL/SQL update trigger errors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, syntax-error

```
create or replace TRIGGER PRODUCT_REORDER_AU
AFTER UPDATE ON PRODUCT
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

IF (PRODUCT.QUANTITY_IN_STOCK < PRODUCT.REORDER_POINT)

THEN

INSERT INTO PURCHASE_ORDER
(PO_NO, PO_DATE, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, SUPPLIER_ID)
VALUES
(OLD.PO_NO, NEW.PO_DATE, OLD.PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID, OLD.PRODUCT.REORDER_QUANTITY, OLD.PRODUCT.SUPPLIER_ID);

END IF;
END;
```

I'm trying to create a trigger to use on an update operation but am getting the following errors:

```
Error(8,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(8,13): PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'PRODUCT.QUANTITY_IN_STOCK' not allowed in this context
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd be inserting purchase orders automatically - into a review queue certainly, or a pending queue of some sort.  Purchasers may want a bit more control over some of this, or for doing things like combined orders.  Also, you probably want to include the count of products on order in this too, or you could end up with more of a product than you want (ie - reorder point for candy bars is 20, and _you_ purchase them in boxes of 100.  But **customers** purchase them a bar at a time...)

Comment: I agree, but for the purposes of this assignment I need to be able to create automatic entries. Thanks for the input though :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you want to check the `:new.quantity_in_stock` and `:new.reorder_point` values.  And remember that the `:new` and `:old` pseudo-records are prefixed with colons.

```
IF (:new.QUANTITY_IN_STOCK < :new.REORDER_POINT)
THEN
  INSERT INTO PURCHASE_ORDER
    (PO_NO, PO_DATE, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, SUPPLIER_ID)
    VALUES
    (:OLD.PO_NO, :NEW.PO_DATE, :OLD.PRODUCT_ID, 
     :OLD.REORDER_QUANTITY, :OLD.SUPPLIER_ID);
END IF;
```

Comment: For the values being inserted, it's throwing an error "bad bind variable"

Comment: @user3385472 - I didn't notice that you had `old.product.column_name` rather than `:old.column_name`.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two things -

1. Don't forget the ":" before old and new.
2. you don't need to write the table name.
   :old.product.product_id can be changed to :old.product_id